# VSS 2015, scss compilation does not overwrite css

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sass

I searched for people with the same issue but unfortunately it doesn't look like a common situation.

My issue is that I make changes in my scss files, hit compile, refresh the browser and getting old css files.

Clearing the browser cache did not work, I disabled IIS outputcache but none worked. So I looked further and found out my .css files are not overwritten after a compilation.

What does help is remove the css files and rebuild all. But that is productivity killer.

I start Visual Studio with elevated permissions; administrator permissions so file access permissions shouldn't be an issue. Visual Studio 2015 has been updated with all latest patches.

I hope someone has another smart suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I started with a fresh Visual Studio 2015 installation loading a project that used the Web Compiler extention before. Somehow a fresh installation still compiles the files but does not overwrite the css.

After installing the Web Compiler extention again, it all works perfectly.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c